# What is the right way to use WebView in React Native

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-webview

**Short summary:**

Trying to use `WebView` from `'react-native-webview'` to render URL content in mobile apps built with React Native is a thorn in my heel.

**Long summary:**

I have used PHP 7 to build approximately 10 websites for my company in the last few months. Now because of some funding from European Union, most of these companies I built the website for also need mobile apps. It is enough to have them only for Android, but it'd be nice to have them for iOS as well.

After quite some googling I (maybe foolishly) decided the best approach would be to use React Native.

Now to elaborate, these apps will be the very simplest and useless apps, only made to check a certain checkbox on some paper.

All the websites I built are already fully mobile responsive so using mobile browser to see and use all they offer is perfectly OK.

That is why it would be perfectly good to just create a mobile native wrapper with webview inside that works exactly like a browser does, albeit without functionality to surf to URLs other than direct links from the website.

**What I did:**

I use VS Code with internal bash terminal (OS = Windows 10)

I installed and update NPM

- Node.js

```
    $ node -v
    v12.8.0
    
    $ npm -v
    6.10.3
```

- Android Studio + SDK
- Android Virtual Device

I opened VS Code terminal in my Projects folder and ran a few commands:

```
    $ npm i -g react-native-cli
    <path>\react-native -> <path>\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js
    + react-native-cli@2.0.1
    
    $ npm i -g yarn
    <path>\yarnpkg -> <path>\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js
    <path>\yarn -> <path>\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js
    + yarn@1.17.3
    
    $ react-native init test1
    /.../
    Done in 68.03s.
    /.../
    Done in 36.62s.
    /.../
    Done in 52.31s.
    
    $ cd test1
    
    $ react-native start
```

Opened another terminal:

```
    $ react-native run-android
```

This created a default Welcome to React app and ran it in emulated Pixel 2 mobile with Marshmallow. So far so good.

I changed the App.js content and imported `Text`, `View`, `AppRegistry` and some others from `'react-native'`, played around, and the app in the emulator accepted everything, even images. So far so good.

I did the same thing with creating a new component and everything is still OK.

**Now the horcrux:**

Facebook's [instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview) tell us to follow the new and improved [`react-native-community/react-native-webview`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview)

```
    $ yarn add react-native-webview@androidx
    yarn add v1.17.3
    /.../
    Done in 28.07s.
    
    $ react-native start
```

My code with just `<View><Text>Hello</Text></View>` in render() still works.

Now I change it to:

```js
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import { AppRegistry, View, Text } from 'react-native';
    import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
    
    export default class test1 extends Component{
      render() {
        return (
          <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/' }} />
        );
      }
    }
    
    AppRegistry.registerComponent('test1', () => test1);
```

And I get an error, saying:
`Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCWebView" was not found in the UIManager.`

Trying `$ react-native link` changes nothing.
Also tried

```
    $ react-native link react-native-webview
    info Linking "react-native-webview" iOS dependency
    info iOS module "react-native-webview" has been successfully linked
    info Linking "react-native-webview" Android dependency
    info Android module "react-native-webview" has been successfully linked
```

but no changes again.

What is the right way to use WebView in React Native?

Comment: Hi, After linking module you need to re run the application using react-native run-android command. Did you tried it?

Comment: Do yo have 
"android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true"
mentioned lines in gradle.properties?

Answer (score 2):

I think u should run :

`cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. && npx react-native run-android`

Comment: You could greatly explain that answer by [edit]ing it and explaining what it does and why it fixes the OP's problem. (And by spelling out "you".) I'd be really curious why you assume that's a Gradle project when the question mentions Node and Yarn. See also [answer].

Comment: @Robert actually the final Android APK is built using Gradle and this advice worked for me.